# Speed up commiting to MySQL DB in python

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I have code that either adds or updates rows in MySQL DB depending if the row ID already exists. I have a loop that iterates through all the ID's in order to do this, and commits each one individually.

However it is very slow. It takes about 20 minutes to update 200,000 rows. I need it to be much faster. Does anyone know how I can commit multiple rows at once to the DB?

Below is my code so far:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://username:password@localhost/dbName'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Example(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'sessionAttendances'
        _id = db.Column('_id', db.Unicode, primary_key=True)
        wondeID = db.Column('wondeID', db.Unicode)
        date = db.Column('date', db.Unicode)
        timezoneType = db.Column('timezoneType', db.Unicode)
        timezone = db.Column('timezone', db.Unicode)
        createdAt = db.Column('createdAt', db.Date)
        session = db.Column('session', db.Unicode)
        updatedAt = db.Column('updatedAt', db.Date)

        def __init__(self, _id, wondeID, date, timezoneType, timezone, createdAt, session, updatedAt):
            self._id = _id
            self.wondeID = wondeID
            self.date = date
            self.timezoneType = timezoneType
            self.timezone = timezone
            self.createdAt = createdAt
            self.session = session
            self.updatedAt = updatedAt

        @classmethod
        def add_or_update(cls, _id, wondeID, date, timezoneType, timezone, createdAt, session, updatedAt):
            entity = cls.query.filter_by(_id=row._id).first()

            if not entity:
                entity = cls(row._id, row.wondeID, row.date, row.timezoneType, row.timezone, row.createdAt, row.session, row.updatedAt)
                db.session.add(entity)
                db.session.commit()
                print("Adding Record")
            else:
                entity.wondeID = row.wondeID
                db.session.commit()
                print("Updating Record")

            return entity

for idx,row in sessionAttendance.iterrows():
    example = Example(row._id, row.wondeID, row.date, row.timezoneType, 
                      row.timezone, row.createdAt, row.session, row.updatedAt)
    example.add_or_update(row._id, row.wondeID, row.date, row.timezoneType, 
                          row.timezone, row.createdAt, row.session, row.updatedAt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that this might be caused by committing rows one by one in `for` loop - this can be a bottleneck which slows down both app's and DB's data processing speed - instead, try to add each batch of data to `db.session` object and then commit it as a whole to DB.

On a side note, I'd highly recommend using dedicated Python library specifically designed for interaction with various database engines (including MS SQL, MySQL etc.), called `pyodbc`.

You can read more about this project here:
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki

You can also check out my project on GH which was focusing on DB transaction (in this case using MS SQL commands' implementation) as a point of reference:
https://github.com/jsarnowski96/pysql-console

Comment: Thanks so much @TheInvisibleMan for replying. I don't suppose you know how I could go about commiting batches instead of one row at a time? I'm very new to this

Comment: if you decide to try pyodbc, you can add every single row of data directly to cursor.Connection object provided by this library, and then commit it to DB as a whole. I think that by using this lib you should be also able to do it one by one like in the original approach, but due to its implementation it should be much, much faster. In addition, commiting data via cursor.Connection doesn't close the connection itself, so you can push much more data without having to reopen transactional session.

Comment: In case of commiting data batches I share the opinion of @miwin about the commit statement after every for loop tick - you should move it outside of the loop and do a one collective commit.

Answer (score 1):

Since your „id“ is your pirmary key, you may want to use session.merge() .

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_state_management.html#merging

This function within SQLAlchemy will automatically create or update an existing item.

I also highly recommend you do not commit after every item.
This is probably the biggest delay in your code.
If your loop does not contain the same „id“ twice, i recommend you commit after your loop is done.

Comment: I tried commiting after the for loop, and also took out the print statements. It now takes 13 minutes for 200,000 rows. But I need to make it even faster

Answer (score 0):

You need to use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. If the row is new then it is inserted, otherwise it is updated.

When using this approach you should insert in batches (ex: 1000 rows at once) and mysql will perform much better running separate queries for all 200.000 rows.

Check this tutorial: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/

Comment: Thanks @Vadim Sirbu for replying so quickly. I did have a look at on duplicate key update, but I couldn't seem to get it to work in python with my dataset. Is there a way of using my existing add_or_update code to speed it up some way?

Comment: I am not familiar with python to be able to help you with an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just try using the psycopg2 database adapter to run the sql command from @Vadim Sirbu with Python.

Comment: Thanks so much @Taru.  Do you know how I could incorporate that into my current code? Can I use it in my add_or_update function?

Comment: At the moment I have no good idea to implement this in your code. But another idea that came to my mind is to solve it within your database, when it is not necessary to display a message after each insert. Most databases support the implementation of triggers, or versioning of data could also be a suitable solution.

Comment: I tried commiting after the for loop, and also took out the print statements. It now takes 13 minutes for 200,000 rows. But I need to make it even faster

Comment: @Pippa97 Additional info request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @Pippa97 To get under 13 minutes, please post data requested by Wilson Hauck on Feb 21, 2020 at 15:33.